# c# how do i access my form controls from my class?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class in the same namespace as my form. Is it possible for me to access methods/properties of my form controls from my class? How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make your controls public, however I wouldn't do that. I'd rather expose just what I need from my controls. So say if I needed access to the text in a text box:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
   public string TextBoxText
   {
      get{return this.textBox1.Text;}
      set{this.textBox1.Text = value;}
   }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing } for the property and as a nitpicky style cop thing - the "this" is unnecessary. Otherwise everything looks good and this is much better than passing around the entire Form.

Comment: Fixed. That's what you get for typing code into a big ass textbox :) As for the "this" being used, we can argue about that forever, but since I don't preface my member variables with underscores (which we can argue about as well) I like to differentiate members from local variables with "this".

Comment: How do you access this within another class? Can someone please provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to pass the form into the class like so:

```
class MyClass
{
     public void ProcessForm(Form myForm)
     {
           myForm.....; // You can access it here
     }

}
```

and expose the Controls that you want so that you can access them but really you should pass only what you need to the class, instead of the whole form itself

Comment: This wouldn't work. All controls are private by default, so even if you pass the form around, you won't be able access any of the controls on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a reference of your form to your class you should be able to access methods and properties of your form from your class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Form form;

    public void GiveForm(Form form)
    {
        this.form = form;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate stubs.

For that

In your custom class write a constructor

```
public YourClass(Main main)   
{
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.main = main;
}
```

then in main class/form class, initialize your class

```
YourClass yesMyClass = YourClass(this);
```

If your want to access form components on your custom class then,

```
this.main.label1.Text="I done that smartly'
```